# Unsupported encoding: DELTA_BYTE_ARRAY when reading from Kusto using Kusto Spark connector or using Kusto export with Spark version < 3.3.0

Tags: apache-spark, export, azure-synapse, azure-data-explorer

Since last week we started getting `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unsupported encoding: DELTA_BYTE_ARRAY` while reading from Kusto using the Kusto Spark connector 'Distributed' mode (same thing happens when trying to use the export command and use parquet read over it). How can we resolve this issue? Is it caused by change from the Kusto service or Spark?

We tried setting the configs "spark.sql.parquet.enableVectorizedReader=false", and "parquet.split.files=false". This works but we are worried about the outcome of this approach.

Answer (score 3):

The change of behavior is due to Kusto rolling out a new implementation of Parquet writer that uses new encoding schemes, one of which being delta byte array for strings and other byte array-based Parquet types. This encoding scheme has been part of the Parquet format for a few years now and modern readers are expected to support it. i.e. Spark 3.3.0. This provides performance and cost improvements and therefore we highly advise customers to move to Spark 3.3.0 or above. Kusto Spark connector is using Kusto export for reading and by that produces parquet files with the new writer.
Possible solutions in case this is not an option:

1. Use Kusto Spark connector version [3.1.10](https://github.com/Azure/azure-kusto-spark/releases/tag/v3.0_3.1.10), which checks the Spark version and disables the writer in the export command if version is less than 3.3.0.
2. Disable Spark configs:
   `spark.conf.set("spark.sql.parquet.enableVectorizedReader", "false").  spark.conf.set("parquet.split.files", "false")`
3. In cases non of the above solves the issue you may open a support ticket to ADX to disable the feature (this is a temporary solution)

Note- Synapse workspace will receive the connector updated version in the following days.

Comment: We're running into this issue in Azure Synapse (Spark 3.2 pool). Do you have an ETA when the spark connector 3.1.10 will be deployed into Synapse runtimes?

Comment: Should be next week